# Replace in Pandas data frame a value in a column according to row name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in pandas that looks like this :

```
prt = {'A' : {'po' : 1000, 
                       'pr' : 15},
             'B' : {'po' : 2000, 
                       'pr' : 6},                         
             'C' : {'po' : 3000, 
                       'pr' : 16}
            };prt
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(prt);A

    A        B       C
po  1000    2000    3000
pr  15       6      16
```

i want to replace the value of pr row name when the column name is A from 15 to 159.How i can do that in Python using Pandas?

Comment: `A.loc['pr', 'A'] = 159`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
A.loc["pr","A"]=159
```